# how to change the quantity of an item added to magento cart during checkout steps

Tags: magento

I have developed a module for a group of tourist to buy trips in a magento store. During the billing step of the checkout, the user fills the form of other partecipant, and according to the number of partecipants i have to change the quantity(qty) of the product to be bought.So it has to be shown in the review step(last step) in checkout, and the grandtotal has to be calculated according that value.
I have tried all the ways but nothing is useful.Can someone help me please.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unclear to answer, I'll still try my best.

What you can do is write a js wherein on the form submit or probably on a filling a particular field you hit an ajax to a controller with the field or form fields details.

In that controller write the below code:

```
//get Product 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
//get Item
$item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);

$quote->getCart()->updateItem(array($item->getId()=>array('qty'=>$qty)));
$quote->getCart()->save();
```

Then refresh your reviews. Your order totals should be updated accordingly.

Comment: Ok, i will simplify my question, in the billing step of checkout i inserted some logic to modify the quantity of the item in the cart. so when i go to last step of checkout(review) i want the quantity to be updated according to my new value inserted in billing.So the grand total have to be calculated according the new value